# Paper.js VS Code not running with script type="text/paperscript"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, paperjs

I'm new to paper.js and I cant use the `type="text/paperscript"`.

When I use `type="text/paperscript"` in my script tag, my editor (VS Code) justs read all of it as text. When I save, it changes all of it.

I am trying to run code from my Udemy class. The code is exactly the same but my editor just can't run it.

When I change it to `type="text/javascript"`, the editor can read and run it, however, I want to use paperscript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely understanding what problem your editor is causing, but here is something to try:
http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/

This page is a tutorial for how to create a paper.js scope without using the type="text/paperscript" attribute.

Basically what you will want to do is create a script tag, and make it a normal type="text/javascript" attribute. In that script tag you will want to get canvas by ID then call paper.setup(canvas); then from there on out you will need to do everything from that paper variable.

```
// Get a reference to the canvas object
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
// Create an empty project and a view for the canvas:
paper.setup(canvas);
```

The drawing example for this "direct javascript" method is:

```
var path = new paper.Path();
// Give the stroke a color
path.strokeColor = 'black';
var start = new paper.Point(100, 100);
// Move to start and draw a line from there
path.moveTo(start);
// Note that the plus operator on Point objects does not work
// in JavaScript. Instead, we need to call the add() function:
path.lineTo(start.add([ 200, -50 ]));
// Draw the view now:
paper.view.draw();
```

Cheers, hope that helps. Obviously you will need some sort of script tag referencing the paperjs library before adding this new script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes\html.json

```
"end": "(?i:(?=/?>|type(?=[\\s=])(?!\\s*=\\s*('|\"|)(text/(javascript|ecmascript|babel)|application/((x-)?javascript|ecmascript|babel)|module)[\\s\"'>])))",
```

To

```
"end": "(?i:(?=/?>|type(?=[\\s=])(?!\\s*=\\s*('|\"|)(text/(javascript|ecmascript|babel|paperscript)|application/((x-)?javascript|ecmascript|babel)|module)[\\s\"'>])))",
```

to get the type paperscript to work.

Ref:  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11781